# upload an images using django and tastypie (python version : 2.7)

Tags: django, python-2.7, file-upload, tastypie, multipartform-data

I am having a hard time figuring out a way of doing multipart/formencoded image upload using django and tastypie.  I went through all the possible answers on stackoverflow but cant seem to find a solution that would work. Also, i am a beginner in python so cant seem to understand a lot of stuff. I have written some code and would like someone to point me as to what am i doing wrong.

Models.py

```
import random

from django.db import models
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
import suuq.settings
from usermanagement import utils
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager
from django.db.models import ImageField



class adManager(models.Manager):
    def create_ad(self, category, title, email, tag, location, address, description, phone, img):

    if not category:
        raise ValueError('add must have a category')

    if not title:
        raise ValueError('add must have a title')

    if not email:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a email')

    if not tag:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a tag')

    if not location:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a location')

    if not address:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a address')

    if not description:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a description')

    if not phone:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a phone number')

    if not img:
        raise ValueError('ad must have a image')    

    ad = self.create(category = category, title = title, email = UserManager.normalize_email(email).strip().lower(), 
        tag = tag, location = location, address = address, description = description, phone = phone, img=img)       
    ad.save()
    return ad

class Ad(models.Model):
    objects = adManager()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(
     max_length=255,
     unique=True,
    )
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)  
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="img", null=True, blank=True)
```

api.py

```
import json

from django.conf.urls import url
from django import forms

from tastypie.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.exceptions import Unauthorized
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.throttle import CacheThrottle
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash
from tastypie.validation import FormValidation
from django.db.models import FileField   
from tastypie import http, fields
from PIL import Image

from ad.models import Ad

class MultipartResource(object):
    def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
    if not format:
        format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
    if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        return request.POST
    if format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)
        return data
    return super(MultipartResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)

class AdResource(ModelResource, MultipartResource):
    img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Ad.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'ad'
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'title','email','tag','location', 'address', 'description', 'phone', 'img']
        allowed_methods = ['post','get','delete']
        include_resource_uri = False


def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/add%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('add_ad'), name="add_ad"),
    ]

def add_ad(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    data = json.loads(request.body)        
    category = data.get('category', '')
    title = data.get('title', '')
    email = data.get('email', '')
    tag = data.get('tag', '')
    location = data.get('location', '')
    address = data.get('address', '')
    description = data.get('description', '')
    phone = data.get('phone', '')
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        if "multipart/form-data" not in str(request.META['CONTENT_TYPE']):
            return 
        else:
            if('img' in request.FILES):
                upload = request.FILES['img']
                img = Image.open(upload)
                return
            else:
                return 
    else:
        return 

    ad = Ad.objects.create_ad(category=category, title=title, email=email, tag=tag, 
        location=location, address=address, description=description, phone=phone, img=img)
    return self.create_response(request, {
        'success': True,
        'ad_id': ad.id,
        'message': 'ad address successfully added' 
    })
```

I know my code is not indented properly but i have it properly indented on my dev end.  Please help me fix my logic, i am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and here is my updated solution using multipart form data

```
class AdResource(ModelResource):
img = fields.FileField(attribute="img", null=True, blank=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Ad.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'ad'
    fields = ['id', 'category', 'title','email','tag','location', 'address', 'description', 'phone', 'img']
    allowed_methods = ['post','get','delete']
    include_resource_uri = False
    always_return_data = True
    limit = 0
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()
    authorization = AdAuthorization()
    throttle = CacheThrottle(throttle_at=200)

def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/add%s$" %
            (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
            self.wrap_view('add_ad'), name="add_ad"),
    ]

def add_ad(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
    format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE')

    if format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)        
        category = data.get('category', '')
        title = data.get('title', '')
        email = data.get('email', '')
        tag = data.get('tag', '')
        location = data.get('location', '')
        address = data.get('address', '')
        description = data.get('description', '')
        phone = data.get('phone', '')
        img = data.get('img','')

        ad = Ad.objects.create_ad(user=request.user, category=category, title=title, email=email, tag=tag, 
            location=location, address=address, description=description, phone=phone, img=img)
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True,
            'message': 'Ad address successfully added',
            'id': ad.id 
        })
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'message': 'Invalid format' 
        })
```